# Proof Verification: $aRb$ iff $\exists c \in A: a,b \in [c]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, relations, equivalence-relations

In an exercise I'm asked to prove the following:

> Let $R$ be an equivalence relation in a set $A$, and let $a,b \in A$, then:
>
> $$aRb \  \text{ iff } \ \exists c \in A: a,b \in [c]$$
> Where $[c]$ is the equivalence class of $c$.

I proved that $\exists c \in A: a,b \in [c] \Rightarrow aRb$, using the fact that $R$ is transitive, but I'm not sure whether my proof for $aRb \Rightarrow \exists c \in A: a,b \in [c]$ is valid. This is what I did:

---

**My proof:**

Let's assume that $aRb$. I'll do this part by contradiction. Let's assume that $\nexists c \in A: a,b \in [c]$. This means that , one of the following is true for all $c \in A$:

- $c R a  \wedge c\not R b$ $\ \ \ $ (1)
- $c \not R a  \wedge c R b$  $\ \ \ $(2)
- $c \not R a  \wedge c\not R b$ $\ \ \ $(3)

If (1):

$c R a \wedge a R b$, so by transitivity $c R b \to$ contradiction

If (2):

$c R b \wedge b R a$, so by transitivity $ c R a \to $ contraditcion

If (3):

$\forall c \in A \setminus \{a,b\}, c \notin [a] \wedge c \notin [b]$. This means that $[a] = [b] = \{a,b\}$, so if we set $c = a$, we have $c R a \wedge c R b \to$ contradiction.

So assuming that $\nexists c \in A: a,b \in [c]$ leads to a contradiction.

---

I think that (1) and (2) are correct but I'm a little sceptical about (3). Did I made some mistake or is this correct?

Comment: In (3) you say $c\in A\setminus\{a,b\}$ and a little bit later, "If $c=a$".... I think it is wrong. BTW if $a\cal R b$ then just take $c=a$ or $c=b$ and you'll have that $a,b\in[c]$.

Comment: That's true @TitoEliatron Thanks

Comment: I'm unsure what the syntax is for wording this.  Show that the contrapositive is true that if a and b belong to different equivalence classes, then it is not the case that aRb.  That is, WLOG a belongs to some equivalence class c and b belongs to some equivalence class d.  What happens if c doesn't equal d?  Does this imply that it is not the case that aRb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is incorrect. In point (3) you stated that "$c \in A \setminus \{a,b\}$" but then you arrived at the conclusion that $c = a$.